# Handling Master Data on (De-)Serialization with JSON.net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Using JSON.NET I am stuck on a issue with MasterData with regards to GET and POST operations.

Using the example of a movie, the JSON I could get on a GET operation before deserializing is the following:

```
{
     “movie”: {
         “name”:”bad boys”,
         ”genre”: {
            “id”:"1",
            ”name”:”thriller”
        }
    }
}
```

However, on a POST operation I would like to construct a serialized string like the following:

```
{
     “movie”: {
         “name”:”bad boys”,
         ”genre”:"1"
    }
}
```

As you can see, with a GET operation I need to deserialize the complete object, while on serialize for POST I need to add the Id only, but with the same JsonPropertyName.

What is the cleanest way to obtain this situation? I've been trying to work on the IContractResolver and IReferenceResolver, but those both didn't get me there yet. Also have been trying to work with propertynames as the following example:

```cs
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre")]
public Genre Genre { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genre")]
public string GenreId { get { return Genre != null ? Genre.Id : 0; } }
```

I've also tried using the ShouldSerialize[MemberName] and ShouldDeserialize[MemberName] situations, but those gave an exception saying I cannot use two properties with the same name, which is logical in a way.

For now, my only idea left is to use a DTO for serialization, but I would rather prefer something more clean than that solution. So open for suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Custom converter.

```
public class GenreConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Genre);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return JObject.Load(reader).ToObject<Genre>();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var genre = value as Genre;
        writer.WriteValue(genre.id);
    }
}
```

All you need now is using `JsonConverter` atttribute

```
public class Movie
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GenreConverter))]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Was just posting this answer myself, after the initial hint from @pavel-krymets. Tried it out and turns out to be just fine. Best solution imo!

Comment: In addition: Because I only need a custom Converter for the Serializing part, I've also used the public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }  which causes the GenreConverter to be ignored for the reading part and use the normal JsonConverter...

Answer (score 1):

Use [custom converter](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) for this. You want to check type of `genre` attribute and read it as `object` or `int`.

Comment: Thanks to your initial hint, I was able to work this out myself. Real answer vote goes to EZI because of the completed example for others for reference purposes, but you where the one to get me there! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, using a DTO *is* the cleanest solution. Since your models are different for GET/POST, you ideally require two separate models. I've abused the `NullValueHandling.Ignore` serializer setting to mean you can use the same model for both situations, providing you don't mind always having the `Id` property on `Genre`:

```
class MovieJsonWrapper
{
    [JsonProperty("movie")]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
}

class Movie
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("genre")]
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

class Genre
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

We can then use this with:

```
var movie = new Movie
{
    Name = "bad boys",
    Genre = new Genre
    {
        Id = "1"
    }
};

var movieJsonWrapper = new MovieJsonWrapper { Movie = movie };

var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movieJsonWrapper, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Which would produce the following:

```
{
  "movie": {
    "name": "bad boys",
    "genre": {
      "id": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

Similarly, we can then deserialize the GET response with:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MovieJsonWrapper>(raw);
```

If you really do need to ditch the `Id` property on the Genre when POSTing, then you would require additional Models. This solution reduces the amount of boilerplate.

Comment: Can feel your opinion regarding having two different models for different purposes. However, because I'm working on an external API I am unable to have any influence on the structure of the JSON that I need to send and receive. Therefore having a custom converter as in the complete example of EZI suited me best. Thanks for the answer though!